# mysqli_fetch_array($link, $query) is not outputting the expected result when querying database directly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mariadb

I am trying to create an array of the table comments per column_name, where column_name is the key.

I go to my mysql database (Maria DB) and enter the query

```
SELECT column_name, column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='apple_checklists'
```

and it returns two columns of information:

[image: Columns]

when I use the phpcode:

```
$columnCommentQuery = "SELECT column_name, column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='apple_checklists'";

$columnComments= mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, $columnCommentQuery), MYSQLI_BOTH);

echo($columnCommentQuery." is_Null ".is_null($columnComments). " after ");

print_r($columnComments);
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

I cannot figure out why I am not getting the result from the query as an output to the array?!?! Originally I was grabbing the comment every time I needed it, but I would rather grab them all at once then look at the array internally to the page.

I tried to be clear, but if more context is needed let me know.I couldn't include the picture because my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: And what you get if not array? I see array (on the line after `after`).

Comment: you ARE getting an array, but the fetch functions only return **ONE** row of data from the result. you need to fetch in a loop.

Comment: The "after" is the printr statement, it doesn't think the array is null. But the array it has does not match the query results that I see when I query directly.

Comment: hmm I guess before when I did this I fetched a whole row and that was how I got a filled array. Why when I run the query on that database does it display all the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$columnCommentQuery = "SELECT column_name, column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='apple_checklists'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $columnCommentQuery);

if ($result) {
    $columnComments= mysqli_fetch_all($result , MYSQLI_BOTH);
    print_r($columnComments);
} else {
    echo('Query: '.$columnCommentQuery.' is wrong ');
}
```

Comment: This gave me an array of arrays. :O

Comment: What did you was expecting? every record is array therefore array of records is array of arrays. what is wrong?

Comment: I would like an array of key is column name - data is comment. If I fetch a row array the key is the column name and the data is what ever was in that column, but I want all the rows for the table. If I had more than two data point, eg  a key for two columns in a particular row, then I would have to have an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();

while($columnComments= mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, $columnCommentQuery), MYSQLI_BOTH)){
     array_push($results,$columnComments);
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: This errors, not enough parentheses, can you have a ; in the while statement?

Comment: @notantisocial I fixed that issue. Thanks